# How can i get the checkbox value in the controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Hello first time asking for help in stackoverflow. My question is this , how will I get the value or model of the selected checkbox.

```
 <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    @foreach (Produto prod in (Model.ProdutosEntrada))
    {
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => prod.Designacao)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => prod.Designacao)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => prod.Descricao)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => prod.Descricao)
        </dd>
        foreach (EntradaProduto entProd in (Model.EntradaProdutoEscolhida))
        {
            if (prod.CodigodoProduto == entProd.CodigodoProduto)
            {
                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => entProd.Quantidade)
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => entProd.Quantidade)
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => entProd.Validado)
                </dt>
                <dd>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="prodValidados" id="@entProd.CodigodoProduto" value="@entProd.Validado"/>*@
                </dd>
            }
        }

    }
</dl>
```

This is the code in the view, i dont know how to redirect to the action and catch the values from the checkboxes.

```
  public ActionResult AtualizarValidado(bool[] prodValidados)
    {

        return null;
    }
```

This is the action, i tried to pass as a argument an array with the same name as the checkbox, but is always null.

If you could help me, will be nice, since i am blocked in this problem for a while.

Comment: Please post your complete `<form>` html element.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your view to:

```
<dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => entProd.Validado)
        </dt>
        <dd>
           @Html.Checkbox("prodValidados")
        </dd>
```

Alter your controller as such:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AtualizarValidado(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection form)
{
    //form["prodValidados"] will return a bool value - checked = true / unchecked = false
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, but doesnt work, the form is null. Can you tell me how can i reedirect to the action?

Comment: Your target url needs to be:  /ControllerName/AtualizarValidado.  You are returning null in the controller.  You will need to complete that code with a true action.  You can run in debug to examine the contents of "form".

Comment: i had used the debbuger and the form is null

Comment: Also, I made the assumption that you had a form declared in your view.  You need to set the target action of the form at the top of your view.   @using (Html.BeginForm("AtualizarValidado", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))

Comment: i have tree checkbox and the return value is for example, "true,false,true,false,true,false" is this case all the check are cheked, why is there falses? And there is any way to pass the model or an id?

Answer (score 0):

The key things here are, in the view it needs to be in a form, which posts to the controller and action, then in the action it needs to be string[] rather than bool[]. Here is a simplified example but it should give you some ideas:

The controller:

```
public ActionResult AtualizarValidado()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AtualizarValidado(string[] prodValidados)
{
    //prodValidados contains the values selected
    return View();
}
```

The view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var entProd in Model.EntradaProdutoEscolhida)
    {
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => entProd.Validado)
        <input type="checkbox" name="prodValidados" value="@entProd.Validado" />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```